# I wish to convert all the lowercase letters of a user given string to '#'.But upon running the code,only the last lowercase char is getting converted

Tags: java, string, replace, lowercase

I wish to convert all the lowercase letters of a user given string to '#'. But upon running the code, only the last lowercase char is getting converted. Could someone suggest a solution to this ? (I am new in java)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class replaceEx{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1,s2=null;
        s1=s.nextLine();
        for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++)
        {
            if(s1.charAt(i)>='a' && s1.charAt(i)<='z')
            s2=s1.replace(s1.charAt(i),'#');
        }
        System.out.println(s2);
    }
}
```

**Input** : ABCDabcd

**Output**: ABCDabc#

Comment: @Jocke that is not what he is asking about, and doesn't cause an issue here.

Comment: @GhostCat , actually Jocke simply points what the problem is. OP thinks that s1.replace() would change the s1. that's why Jocke pointed it out.

Comment: @hunter That is not correct. The OP assigns **and** prints to s2, not s1. See my answer for a better explanation of what is going on here!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here:

```
s2=s1.replace(s1.charAt(i),'#');
```

What happens is: s2 becomes **s1**, where that char at i gets replaced with '#'.

You assume that somehow s2 remembers **previous** assignments. It doesn't.

In other words: your code does call:

```
s2=s1.replace('a','#');
s2=s1.replace('b','#');
s2=s1.replace('c','#');
s2=s1.replace('d','#');
```

So, s2 becomes assigned ABCD#bcd, ABCDa#cd, ABCDab#d, ABCDabc#. And as said: only that last assignment sticks. Worse: `replace()` doesn't care about that index `i` that you used for `charAt()`. It simply replaces the **first** occurrence of the char to look for. In other words: if your word is "Aaba", you *always* keep replacing only that *first* 'a' with #.

In other words: your whole approach can't work, for multiple reasons.

There are multiple ways to solve this, for example to use [`replaceAll()`](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/string/java-string-replaceall-example/). That method **also** allows to use regular expressions, so that you can say (in one call) "replace all lowercase chars with #" easily.

Another approach would be:

- create a StringBuilder sb
- iterate your s1 string
- if a char is a lowercase letter: append # to sb
- otherwise append the char
- in the end, turn sb into a real string

Comment: Changed the line from  s2=s1.replace(s1.charAt(i),'#'); to s2=s1.replaceAll("[a-z]", "#"); and it worked correctly. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

@GhostCat answer is great and strait to point and I wanted to show an example he pointed out by using Java streams feature. Take a look at it:

```
    String simpleText = "What is a weather like? Day is beitufil.";
    // int 32 is equal to empty space character ' '
    String processedText  = simpleText.chars().mapToObj(i -> i != 32 ? '#' : (char)i).collect(StringBuilder::new, (text, character) -> text.append((char)character), StringBuilder::append).toString();
    System.out.println(processedText);
```

Comment: You can compare `i` directly with `' '` instead of the cryptic 32.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Sure, I have made it that way first time( and edited ), but then I didn't want to confuse him, since chars() gets us a stream of integers. @DodgyCodeException

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
//class name should be start with capital letter in java
class ReplaceEx{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
     Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
     String s1,s2=null;
     s1=s.nextLine();
     //Changed below line from s2=s1.replace(s1.charAt(i),'#') to
     s2=s1.replaceAll("[a-z]", "#");
     System.out.println(s2);
   }
}
```

Comment: Just one `s1.replaceAll` is enough. No need to put it in a loop.